# Multiple plots in 1 figure using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got data in the below format, and what I'm trying to do is to:

1) loop over each value in Region
2) For each region, plot a time series of the aggregated (across Category) sales number.

> Date         |Region    |Category    | Sales
>   01/01/2016| USA| Furniture|1
>   01/01/2016| USA| Clothes |0
>   01/01/2016| Europe| Furniture|2
>   01/01/2016| Europe| Clothes |0
>   01/02/2016|    USA| Furniture|3
>   01/02/2016|    USA|Clothes|0
>   01/02/2016|    Europe| Furniture|4
>   01/02/2016|    Europe| Clothes|0   ...

The plot should look like the attached (done in excel).

[image]

However, if I try to do it in Python using the below, I get multiple charts when I really want all the lines to show up in one figure.

Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\wusm\Desktop\Book7.csv')


plt.legend()
for index, group in df.groupby(["Region"]):
    group.plot(x='Date',y='Sales',title=str(index))

plt.show()
```

Short of reformatting the data, could anyone advise on how to get the graphs in one figure please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Region', values='Sales', aggfunc='sum')
print (df)
Region      Europe  USA
Date                   
01/01/2016       2    1
01/02/2016       4    3
```

or [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['Date', 'Region'])['Sales'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
Region      Europe  USA
Date                   
01/01/2016       2    1
01/02/2016       4    3
```

and then [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```
df.plot()
```

Comment: Glad can help, nice weekend!